# Problem with react-native-material-dropdown animation on click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I recently added react-native-material-dropdown to my React Native app and I feel like it is a great library but the documentation is sometimes unclear.

When I implemented this library into my code, I ran into this problem, the animation on click on my dropdown is broken.

I looked into the code and the dropdown should be a `TouchableWithoutFeedback` so I'm wondering why I have this glitchy visual effect.

**EDIT**: The visual effect looks that bad when I implement renderBase but if I don't, I can just see a tinier visual problem that is the shadow of the animation going off the bottom of the button a little bit.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Dropdown animation]

My implementation is the following

```
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown'

<DropdownView>
  <Dropdown
    containerStyle={styles.containerStyle}
    data={data}
    fontSize={hp('2.7%')}
    inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainerStyle}
    itemCount={5}
    itemTextStyle={styles.itemTextStyle}
    labelExtractor={({ value, icon }) =>
      renderCheckboxRow(value, icon)
    }
    onChangeText={text => setCountryCode(text)}
    renderBase={({ value }) => renderCheckbox(value)}
    value={countryCode}
    valueExtractor={({ value }) => pickCountryCode(value)}
  />
</DropdownView>
```

`renderCheckbox` returns this

```
 <BaseCheckboxView>
    <Image source={icon} />
    <BaseCheckboxText>{value}</BaseCheckboxText>
  </BaseCheckboxView>
```

My styles

```
const BaseCheckboxView = styled.View`
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: ${hp('16%')};
`

const Image = styled.Image``

const BaseCheckboxText = styled.Text`
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Baloo-Regular';
  font-size: ${hp('4%')};
  margin-left: ${wp('2%')};
`
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem after I changed the dropdownOffset:

```
dropdownOffset={{top: 0, left: 0}}
```

After that the "ripple" effect was out of alignment and i fixed it by change the rippleInsets property like so:

```
rippleInsets={{top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0}}
```

The documentation for rippleInsets implies only top and bottom properties but my typescript was complaining that the object was missing left and right properties as well.

Hope this helps!